# Loading resources from within a static block in Swing

Tags: java, swing

I'm currently using this kind of code to load resources for my application. Example:

```
public class MyResources {

    private static final String FONT_FILE = "path/to/resource";

    private static Font font;

    static {

        try (InputStream is = MyResources.class.getResourceAsStream(FONT_FILE)) {
            font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is).deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 15f);
        } catch (IOException | FontFormatException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not load font: " + FONT_FILE);
        }

        // .....
        // other resources here
        // .....

    }

    public static Font getFont() {
        return font;
    }

}
```

And then I use the font from any class I want:

```
label.setFont(MyResources.getFont());
```

Is it a good practice to load resources (fonts, images, etc.) from within a static initializer? In general, what would be considered the best practice for loading resources (that will be used multiple times from different classes) in a Swing application?

Comment: @Arvind all files are inside a `resources` folder which is inside `src` and the above code works for me. Should I add a slash anyway?

Comment: This is a classic use-case for Dependency Injection such as Spring. Are you already using Spring?

Comment: @Jim Garrison never heard of it until now...